# VB.NET JSON CLASS

Tags: json, vb.net

Good Morning

Thank you for taking the time to read this post, greatly appreciated.

I am new to JSON and originally a VB programmer so am also getting to grips with VB.NET

I have the following JSON data that I need to be able to create via VB.NET and then serialize so that the output matches the below as I will be sending this data to a web service.

The JSON is as below:-

```
    '{
    '  "warehouseName": "WareHouseName",
    '  "originAddress": {
    '    "name": "Name",
    '    "company": "Company.",
    '    "street1": "Street1",
    '    "street2": "Street1",
    '    "street3": "Street1",
    '    "city": "City",
    '    "state": "AB",
    '    "postalCode": "80012",
    '    "country": "US",
    '    "phone": "512-111-2222",
    '    "residential": true
    '  },
    '  "returnAddress": null,
    '  "isDefault": false
    '}
```

I can generate a class etc. for this using VB.NET paste special JSON as CLASS which would give me:-

```
Public Class WareHouse
    Public Property warehouseName As String
    Public Property originAddress As Originaddress
    Public Property returnAddress As Object
    Public Property isDefault As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Originaddress
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property company As String
    Public Property street1 As String
    Public Property street2 As Object
    Public Property street3 As Object
    Public Property city As String
    Public Property state As String
    Public Property postalCode As String
    Public Property country As String
    Public Property phone As String
    Public Property residential As Boolean
End Class
```

What I'm not sure of is how I can code this to output in the same format, I can output a singlular class at a time w/out issue but how I do combine them, if that makes sense?

```
    Dim NewWareHouse As New WareHouse
    NewWareHouse.warehouseName = "Test"

{
  "warehouseName": "Test",
  "originAddress": null,
  "isDefault": false
}


Dim NewOriginAddress As New Originaddress
NewOriginAddress.name = "Test"
NewOriginAddress.company = "Company"
NewOriginAddress.street1 = "Street1"
NewOriginAddress.street2 = "Street2"
NewOriginAddress.street3 = "Street3"
NewOriginAddress.city = "City"
NewOriginAddress.state = "State"
NewOriginAddress.postalCode = "HP2 7BN"
NewOriginAddress.phone = "01442430690"
NewOriginAddress.residential = False
Dim jsonTxt As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewOriginAddress, Formatting.Indented)
Debug.Print(jsonTxt)

{
  "name": "Test",
  "company": "Company",
  "street1": "Street1",
  "street2": "Street2",
  "street3": "Street3",
  "city": "City",
  "state": "State",
  "postalCode": "HP2 7BN",
  "country": null,
  "phone": "01442430690",
  "residential": false
}
```

I need to combine so that the output matches the original JSON?

All help, pointers etc. greatly appreciated, be gentle :)

Comment: After creating the instance of OriginAddress (NewOriginAddress) set the property _originAddress_ of the WareHouse instance (NewWareHouse) with the NewOriginAddress then serialize just NewWareHouse

Comment: Try setting NewWareHouse.OriginalAddress=NewOriginAddress  and then Dim jsonTxt As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewWareHouse, Formatting.Indented) - note: you should JsonCovert NewWareHouse NOT NewOriginAddress

Comment: Both of these comments were helpful in figuring out the issue, I don't think I was too far off but did need clarification, so thank-you.  I'm going to go with the suggestion by @JonRoberts simply because he added additional code comments.  Can you post that comment as the answer so I can update the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
NewOriginAddress.residential = False
NewWareHouse.originAddress = NewOriginAddress
Dim jsonTxt As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewWareHouse, Formatting.Indented)
Debug.Print(jsonTxt)
```

the issue is that you need to serialise NewWareHouse, not NewOriginAddress